# Sum Lists function in Scala

Tags: scala

> **Sum Lists:** You have two numbers represented by a linked list, where each node contains a single digit. The digits are stored in
>   reverse order, such that the 1 's digit is at the head of the list.
>   Write a function that adds the two numbers and returns the sum as a
>   linked list.
>
> EXAMPLE
>
> Input: (7-> 1 -> 6) + (5 -> 9 -> 2).That is,617 + 295
>
> Output: 2 -> 1 -> 9. That is, 912

Is there any way to improve the code?

```
def sumList(list1:List[Int], list2:List[Int], curry: Int):List[Int]= (list1.size,list2.size) match {
    case (0,0)=>List.empty
    case (0, b) =>sumList(List.empty, list2.tail, if(list2.head+curry>10)(list2.head+curry)/10 else 0):::List((list2.head+curry)%10)
    case (a,0)  =>sumList(list1.tail,List.empty , if(list1.head+curry>10)(list1.head+curry)/10 else 0):::List((list1.head+curry)%10)
    case (a,b) =>sumList(list1.tail,list2.tail, if(list1.head+list2.head+curry>10)(list1.head+list2.head+curry)/10 else 0):::List((list1.head+list2.head+curry)%10)
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Naming

  - Use something shorter and more generic, like `a` and `b`, instead of `list1` and `list2`
  - `curry` is mispelled -- should be `carry`
- You are repeating yourself a lot.  For example, except in the case where both lists are empty:

  - In each case, you have three adds that are exactly the same.
  - All three cases have a very similar structure -- the only difference is basically which numbers are being added
- Consider defining a class to represent numbers.  That way, you can easily change the representation in the future.
- I don't think your implementation is tail-recursive.  This will lead to stack-overflows for large lists.  This might or might not be a problem, depending on your application.
- Use "[word-at-a-time](http://www.thocp.net/biographies/papers/backus_turingaward_lecture.pdf)" thinking only as a last resort.  In this case, you are directly recursing over the lists -- one element ("word") at a time.  Try to find a higher-level abstraction, such as [`map`](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/), that you can use.

  In this particular case, in order to handle the carries, you really need some sort of "`map` plus accumulator" abstraction.  To my knowledge, there is no such function built-in to Scala.  So you might have to write your own.  Still, I would suggest implementing a generic, higher-order function to do this.  That way, you can reuse that function later for other things.
- Try to decompose your problem.  In this case, the problem is already fairly simple.  Still, you might (or might not -- I'm not sure) benefit from drawing inspiration from [hardware adders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)).

Comment: Hi I am not sure the problem is, can you help to give a solution so that I can compare with mine and to see where is problem, thanks

Comment: May I know why you think mine is not tail-recursive ?

Comment: @sweetyBaby, it's not tail-recursive because the last thing the function does (in the recursive cases) is invoke the `:::` operator.  Thus, the recursive call to `sumList` is not in tail position.  As I mentioned, I think you should use a higher-level abstraction rather than using recursion directly in this particular situation.  But if you'd like to learn more about tail-recursion see https://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/09/27/tail-recursion-basics-in-scala/

Answer (score 1):

- I would do it in multiple steps:
  convert to int(or Biginteger) -> calculate -> convert to linked list
- you can use the commutivity of addition for

  case (a,0) => sumList(list2,list1, 0)

Comment: I suppose that converting to an `Int` or `BigInteger` would defeat the intended purpose of this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is wrong: for your given example, it produces the list `9 → 1 → 2`, which is backwards.  Furthermore, it takes a `curry` (which should be "carry"?) parameter that is not in my interpretation of the spec.

Your solution tries to handle too many cases all at once.  As @NathanDavis says, a more functional approach would be useful.  To start, I would recommend naïvely adding the digits without carrying.  Then, write a `carry` function that traverses the list and carries the excess values towards the end of the list.

```
def sumList(aList: List[Int], bList: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  def carry(list: List[Int]): List[Int] = list match {
    …
  }

  carry(aList.zipAll(bList, 0, 0).map((pair) => pair._1 + pair._2))
}
```